# Pack a Zend Framework app and deploy it on Zend Server

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

I created a small Zend Framework application from command prompt using Zend_Tool.

I deployed it in apache server htdocs folder and it is running fine.

Now I need to deploy it to Zend Server. For that i used a command `zdpack pack appname`. 
While trying that i am getting lot of errors like

> deployment.xml is missing

I created it in the app root folder.
Then i got

> appnaama/data folder is missing error

I created a data folder.
Then

> zend-scripts missing

error....

Please help me in deploying an applicaiton created from `zf create project projname` in Zend server and run it in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to come out of the directory when calling ***zdpack pack*** command. If you pack the file inside the project directory you get the "*deployment.xml is missing*" error.

> Pass the following commands at the location where you are creating the
>   *zpk file.* For illustration, I will be doing it in the myapp folder of my desktop.

```
C:\Users\lura\Desktop\myapp> zdpack.exe create demoapp
```

Move into the directory using cd demoapp and list the directory. Copy your php codes into the data folder. The scripts folder and deployment.xml file can be left as it is. Next run the validate command when inside the directory.

```
C:\Users\lura\Desktop\myapp\demoapp> zdpack.exe validate --schema="C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\deployment.xsd" deployment.xml
```

now you can move a folder back with the command cd .. and execute the following.

```
C:\Users\lura\Desktop\myapp>zdpack pack demoapp
```

That's it! The zpk file is created! [A screenshot of my cmd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63xat.png)

This [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=12&v=C1LtN6uFhx4) will help, if your still confused. To execute on Linux and for more info read this [documentation](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/preparing_the_library_package_using_the_deployment_tool.htm) from zend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just pass incorrect path to the app.
Try following this scheme:

```
zdpack pack <path>/ProjectName
```

to generate required files.

Comment: The link you posted shows **Not Found**. Please check and update.

Comment: Apparently zend team removed the tutorial - I removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using zdpack command wrong!

```
Step 1: Open shell and ls or cd into the zend workspace.
Step 2: use "zdpack create <ProjectName>" command. It will create deployment.xml, data and script directories. Refresh project explorer you will see changes.
Step 3: Configure deployment.xml if needed.
Step 4: Use "zdpack pack <ProjectName>" command to create zpk file.
```

That's all.

Comment: I get command no found :( On ubuntu /usr/local/zend/bin , there is a zdpack file in that directory but i cant seem to use it

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create skeleton from the zend server zdpack command

```
#/usr/local/zend/bin/zdpack create <project-name>
```

It will create project skeleton.

**Step 2:** Configure deployment.xml if needed.After that check your Deployment.xml is valid.

```
# /usr/local/zend/bin/zdpack validate --schema="/usr/local/zend/share/deployment.xsd" deployment.xml
```

**Step 3:** Now create the zpk file for the aplication

```
# /usr/local/zend/bin/zdpack pack <project-name>
```